# How do I replicate items from a list in Clojure?

Tags: list, clojure

I've tried this for so many nights that I've finally given up on myself. Seems like an extremely simple problem, but I guess I'm just not fully understanding Clojure as well as I should be (I partially attribute that to my almost sole experience with imperative languages). The problem is from hackerrank.com

Here is the problem:

```
Problem Statement


 Given a list repeat each element of the list n times. The input and output 
portions will be handled automatically by the grader.

Input Format 
    First line has integer S where S is the number of times you need to repeat 
elements. After this there are X lines, each containing an integer. These are the 
X elements of the array.

Output Format 
    Repeat each element of the original list S times. So you have to return 
list/vector/array of S*X integers. The relative positions of the values should be 
same as the original list provided as input.

Constraints 
0<=X<=10 
1<=S<=100
```

So, given:

```
2
1
2
3
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

I've tried:

```
(fn list-replicate [num list]
    (println (reduce 
        (fn [element seq] (dotimes [n num] (conj seq element)))
        []
        list))
)
```

But that just gives me an exception. I've tried so many other solutions, and this probably isn't one of my better ones, but it was the quickest one I could come up with to post something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defn list-replicate [num list]
  (mapcat (partial repeat num) list))
```

---

```
(doseq [x (list-replicate 2 [1 2 3])]
  (println x))

;; output:
1
1 
2
2
3 
3
```

Comment: as far as I know partial is considered badly readable, 
so lambda is recommended instead

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is short and it works, but it is very "compressed" and is not easy for new people to learn.  I would do it in a simpler and more obvious way.

First, look at the `repeat` function:

```
user=> (doc repeat)
-------------------------
clojure.core/repeat
([x] [n x])
  Returns a lazy (infinite!, or length n if supplied) sequence of xs.

user=> (repeat 3 5)
(5 5 5)
```

So we see how to easily repeat something N times.

What if we run (repeat n ...) on each element of the list?

```
(def N 2)
(def xvals [1 2 3] )
(for [curr-x xvals]
  (repeat N curr-x))
;=> ((1 1) (2 2) (3 3))
```

So we are getting close, but we have a list-of-lists for output. How to fix?  The simplest way is to just use the `flatten` function:

```
(flatten
  (for [curr-x xvals]
    (repeat N curr-x)))
;=> (1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

Note that both `repeat` and `for` are lazy functions, which I prefer to avoid unless I really need them.  Also, I usually prefer to store my linear collections in a concrete vector, instead of a generic "seq" type. For these reasons, I include an extra step of forcing the results into a single (eagar) vector for the final product:

```
(defn list-replicate [num-rep orig-list]
  (into []
    (flatten
      (for [curr-elem xvals]
        (repeat N curr-elem)))))

(list-replicate N xvals)
;=> [1 1 2 2 3 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're very correct in saying that the answer is very compressed and hard to comprehend for beginners! It really posed the question for me, "How am I ever going to learn what functions to use given a problem?" because the answer isn't completely intuitive to me as a beginner. Coming from imperative languages, you code is a little more comfortable to understand.

Comment: So, you say you generally avoid `repeat` and `for`; what can I use in place of those or does it depend on the problem at hand? I'm trying to learn Clojure with a good foundation.

Comment: I just meant that I prefer to avoid lazy functions, or force the answer into a concrete eager vector at the end (as I have done here). Get "Clojure Programming" by Emerick et al, and bookmark the Clojure Cheatsheet http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html    Study each function and slowly remember them all.  The links to http://clojuredocs.org/ have lots of good examples.

Comment: @AlanThompson Can you reference a source your avoidance of "lazy" functions.  I believe such avoidance is unidiomatic, but I'm also not 100% sure.  :)

Comment: @AlanThompson I actually do already have the book, but I will definitely bookmark that cheatsheet.

Comment: @event_jr, Most of the time it won't matter, but it can cause problems is you get a lazy collection that is the output of a DB or a file read, then then DB connection or file handle closes and the lazy collection has not actually read the data yet. Then you get an Exception. Also, I normally would rather pass around bits of data than a "formula" for generating the data. I would actually turn the question around: When is laziness a benefit? Only if you have very large data that you won't all process or that you want to process incrementally.  Otherwise, I prefer "Keep it Simple!"

Comment: @AlanThompson Laziness is not just about processing large collections.  it's a shift in computation structure.  The core API produces lazy results whenever possible, so it's hard to avoid even if you tried.  You can always `doall` to everything, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest building onto Alan's solution and instead of flatten use concat as this will preserve the structure of the data in case you have input sth like this [[1 2] [3 4]].

```
    ((fn [coll] (apply concat (for [x coll] (repeat 2 x)))) [[1 2] [3 4]])

    output: => ([1 2] [1 2] [3 4] [3 4])
```

unlike with flatten, which does the following

```
    ((fn [coll] (flatten (for [x coll] (repeat 2 x)))) [[1 2] [3 4]])

    output: => (1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4)
```

as for simple lists e.g. '(1 2 3), it works the same:

```
   ((fn [coll] (apply concat (for [x coll] (repeat 2 x)))) '(1 2 3))

   output => (1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(reduce #(count (map println (repeat %1 %2))) num list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(fn [num lst] (for [e lst _ (range num)] (println e)))
```

the same with lambda:

```
#(for [e %2 _ (range %)] (println e))
```